# Why does my array lose all data when exiting loop

Tags: vbscript

This is my first post here but reading other posts has helped me with countless issues.  You guys are awesome.  So thanks for all the help you guys have provided up to this point and thanks in advance for any advice you can give me here.

So, I'm working on this script that will end up randomly choosing numbers from a list in an array.  What I'm trying to do in this section is read the number in each element of the third dimension of `NumberHistoryArray` and write the corresponding number from the second dimension the number of times indicated in the third into the `numberDump` array.  I also have it writing to a text file just to see that it works and to have something to reference if I run into other problems and need to know what the output is.

*Edit*
The second dimension of NumberHistoryArray contains the numbers 1 through 35.  The third dimension contains the number of times each of the numbers in the second dimension should be repeated when written to the numberDump array.

If NumberHistoryArray(4, 0, 0) is 4, for example, it should write the number 1 four times, once each in numberDump(0, 0, 0) through (0, 0, 3) and dynamically resize numberDump() as needed to fit each 1.  The result of echoing numberDump(0, 0, 0) through numberDump(0, 0, 3) should be 1 1 1 1.  If NumberHistoryArray(4, 1, 1) is 7, it should write the number 2 seven times in numberDump(1, 1, 0).
*Edit*

When writing to the numberDump text file from within the Do loop, the text file is perfect. If I echo the contents of each element in the array from inside the Do loop, the contents are accurate. Once outside the Do loop, the contents are blank. Any takers?

```
Dim NumberHistoryArray(5, 34, 3)
Dim numberDump()
reDim numberDump(3, 34, 0)

' generate the number list and store it in the array
For n = LBound(numberDump, 1) to UBound(numberDump, 1)
  i = 1
  x = 0
  y = 1

  Do
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("numberDump.txt", 8, True)

    ' determine how many elements are needed in the third dimension of the
    ' array to store the output
    x = x + NumberHistoryArray(4, i - 1, n)

    ' resize the array
    ReDim Preserve numberDump(3, 34, x)

    ' input the numbers
    For z = y to UBound(NumberDump, 3)
      numberDump(n, i - 1, z) = i
      objTextFile.WriteLine(numberDump(n, i - 1, z))
    Next

    objTextFile.Close

    y = x + 1
    i = i + 1
  Loop Until i = 36
Next

For i = 0 to UBound(numberDump, 2)
For j = 0 to UBound(numberDump, 3)
    wscript.Echo numberDump(0, i, j)
Next
Next
```

Comment: I might just be tired, but I'm having trouble understanding your goal. Any chance you could include some code that initializes `NumberHistoryArray` and `numberDump`, and also the code you're using to echo the array contents outside the Do loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are resizing the third dimension of `numberDump` to `x` each iteration, and you are resetting the value of `x` with each iteration of `n`. For example, when `n` is 0, by the end of the `Do` loop, `x` may be equal to 10. However, on the next iteration, when `n` is 1, `x` is reset to 0 and you end up resizing the third dimension of `numberDump` to 0, erasing most of the existing elements.

There are two methods of working around this:

1. Keep track of the maximum value of `x` for *all* iterations of `n`. Use that value to resize `numberDump` as necessary.
2. Use a jagged array (aka, an array of arrays). In this case, `numberDump` would be a two-dimensional array whose values are arrays containing the repeated values. This would allow each value to have a different length, as opposed to a three-dimensional array, where the third dimension always has the same length.

Comment: Holy crap, I can't believe I missed that x = 0 was inside the outer loop.  You, sir, are awesome.  In addition, your suggestion of jagged arrays solves another problem I was going to have further down the line.  Looks like I've got some re-writing to do.  Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

**Ever heard of life span of objects?** Where do you initialize the objects : within a loop or outside the loop so that it can be referred within the entire `sub routine`/`function`.

How do you refer to `Array elements` outside the `loop`? Each `element` has an `index`. So you elment is referred via the `index`.

e.g. ArrayOne has 3 elements from `Lower bound` 0 to 2. Within your loops you can refer to `ArrayOne(1)` to get 2nd element.

Other than using indices to refer elements, you can also try to view array elements during the `debug mode` on `immediate window` or `watch window`.

So as you check on these tips, please show us a proper complete code for further verification.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  I'm having trouble putting the goal into words.  The script is really long so I'll try to include what's necessary to get the idea.  Also, I'm doing this in Notepad++ so I'm not sure what debugging tools are available.  I've just been inserting wscript.Echo lines to see the output at certain points and then removing it when I have that section working.

Comment: It's alright. :) Give a buzz when you are ready. My key board has aproblem sddnly. Most keys seems to be misissng. So can'ttype mucof a mesage here.

Comment: In VBScript, there are are only two scopes: global and local within a procedure. Whether or not the objects are initialized inside the loop or not should have no bearing on whether they can be referred to outside the loop. That being said, it is always good advice to use `Option Explicit` at the top of the script and explicitly declare all variables using `Dim`.

Comment: Option Explicit, eh?  I'll look into that.  I've initialized each of the arrays outside of the loop and I'm not using any Subs yet so nothing is contained inside a procedure.  I've updated the code in the original post and added some clarification in what it's supposed to do.  I really appreciate you guys taking the time to help me with this.